# Automatic command line input from python script into running python shell-script

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, command-line

I have a python shell script that is formatted by importing CMD and with commands structured as `do_*(self, arg)`. The script works perfect when I input to the command line, but I am trying to write a script that will process data, determine what command to run and input the command to the shell while it is running to execute the desired command. Is this a possibility, and if so, how might this be done?

example:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
class exampleShell(cmd.Cmd):
def do_exit(self, inp):
        print("Bye")
        return True
MyPrompt().cmdloop()
```

So, if I run the script and type exit into the command line, it will print "Bye" but I want to be able to run a seperate script that can send the exit command to the script without inputting it myself.

Comment: Can you please describe the desired operation in more detail? An example would help.

Comment: I have figured out that exampleShell().onecmd('exit') would simulate the input and execute the command if I put that within the shell script, but I am trying to put that in a different script.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are trying to write a command interpreter *and* allow access to its commands to Python scripts?

Consider factoring out the common part, and import it from the interpreter, or from other scripts.

```py
# commands.py

def foo(params): ...
def bar(params): ...
```

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# interpreter; use it as a shell command / REPL.

import commands

class Shell(cmd.Cmd):
  def do_foo(self, params):
    return commands.foo(params)
  # etc
```

```py
# another-script.py; use it to run complex custom logic.

import commands

def someLogic(x):
  if x > 1:
    commands.foo(x)
  else:
    commands.bar(x + 100)
```

It's still hard to tell what kind of a solution helps until yo explain a bit more what is the *real* problem you are solving.